# Restriction of 1 download at a time in PHP

Tags: php, download

I am working on a video site that has different movies and videos which users can stream and download. Now I am being asked to implement a download restriction in such a way that only 1 video can be downloaded at a time. There are two servers: my files and database are on one server and the videos are on the other.

What I am doing for downloading is to send a request from the first server for a file on the other server. If the requested video exists, it is downloaded.

Now I want to restrict the users so that if they are already downloading a video, they cannot download another until the current download completes. Once the current download has completed, the user can download the next video. I have not seen any function that enables a developer to know when the download has completed.

I have a few things in my mind about storing the information of the download time in the database. But storing the time of download is not my requirement.

What is the best way to implement this? Is there an event from which we can detect the download end time? Is there any solution to this? I am using PHP and here is the code that I have used for downloading the file from the second (videos) server. This file sends a request with a file name and full path. The `$real_file` variable contains the file name along with full path on the second server.

```
if(file_exists($real_file))
{
    header("Pragma: public"); 
    header("Cache-Control: private"); 
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Encoding: none');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".urlencode(basename($real_file)));   
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");            
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($real_file));
    header("Accept-Length: ".filesize($real_file));

    $fp = @fopen($real_file, "rb");

    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        $buffer= fread($fp, 8192);
        echo $buffer;
    }

    @flush();
    @ob_flush();
    die();
}
```

Comment: You will need to add more information about your setup and what you are using to serve the files, your server configuration, etc.

Comment: @Pekka now is it complete or still a room of more information?

Comment: What code are you using to pass through the download files?

Comment: What does he use for download? Is it streamed in a flash player or equivalent? Maybe you want to look into mod_bw or other server modules that can restrict the amount of simultaneous IPs etc.

Comment: @Pekka. Using header function and then file read to download the file.

Comment: @jishi. No wmv player is used for streaming. Even if IP is traced then how can I restrict 1 Download at a time. User can only download other video when first is completed

Comment: @Awais hmm. You should be able to have your program signal when it is done sending a file, shouldn't you? Like, write it into a database and then when the client requests the next download, check whether one is running for that IP... An Apache based approach would however be worth a look too, because it's likely to be more easy on resources.

Comment: @Pekka. This is the thing that I want to ask that how can I check that 1 download is being running. Have you any code example for that?

Comment: @Awais it should be half-way straightforward: When the download starts, write into a database table: The client IP, the file being downloaded, and a unique random ID. When the download is finished, remove that line from the database. To check whether any downloads are running for a client, do a `SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ip = '12.34.56.78'` and count the results.

Comment: You just need to take into consideration the possibility that a download crashes, and fails to remove its line from the database. In that case, maybe check for records older than x minutes and ignore those automatically

Comment: @Peka Sorry I think I am still unable to understand that when the download is being running how can I check? At what event I should execute this query?

Comment: @Awais before you start serving a second download. If there is a record in the table, deny the download with a "sorry, you have to wait..." message.

Comment: @pekka. I have placed my code of download. Would you like to tell me where now how to do that job./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stream the file through a php-script, it would maybe be able to obtain a lock for a specific user (logged in of course) before you start to read the file and outputting to the stream:

(pseudocode)

```
obtain_lock_somehow();
readfile('yourvideofile.mpg');
release_lock();
```

I don't know how the script would respond to a closed connection, and it might force the script to end prematurely.

Another option would be to read the file and pass on to the stream in "chunks", and in between every chunk you update the status of the visitors "lock", so that you can identify at which last timestamp the visitor actually downloaded something.

(pseudocode)

```
while(file_is_not_finished) {
    update_lock_status();
    pass_thru_buffer();
}
```

But do note that streaming huge amount of data in a php-script like this is probably not the best way to go, and you might be better off with a native server module for it.

Comment: hi dude thanks for your response. Now please see my question again. I have put my code which I am using for download. Will you please tell me now how to do that?

Comment: How will you identify a unique visitor? By its ip? By any querystring parameters (eg, ha passkey of some sort)? You have two options here, either use a lock file which the page can look for, or use a database to store locks in. If you don't already have a database a lock file is probably the best way.